# Как запускать страницу с использованием ReactJS без использования сервера?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Я использую расширение Live Server для Visual Studio Code. Когда я запускаю страницу с помощью этого расширения, всё работает нормально, но когда я просто открываю index.html (откуда запускаются все скрипты, загружается ReactJS, JSX) в браузере, ничего не работает.
HTML Код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>My Projects</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script> <!-- For ReactJS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script> <!-- For ReactJS too -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js" crossorigin></script> <!-- For JSX -->
    <script src="App.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

App.js:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))

class Button extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }
    handleClick() {
        window.open(this.props.link, '_blank');
    }
    render() {
        return <button id={this.props.ID} className={this.props.Class} onClick={this.handleClick}>GitHub</button>
    }
}

class Panel extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.inner = this.props.inner
    }
    render() {
        return <div className="Panel">{this.inner}</div>
    }
}

class Image extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.inner = this.props.inner
    }
    render() {
        return <img src={this.props.Source} className="Panel-Image"/>
    }
}

function App() {
    return <div>
        <Panel inner={ <div> <Button ID="github_button" Class="Button" link="https://github.com/mikhail-zh-2009/React-Page"/> ReactJS Calculator <br/> <Image Source="project-react-page.png"/> </div> }/>
        <Panel inner={ <div> <Button ID="github_button" Class="Button" link="https://github.com/mikhail-zh-2009/React-Page-2"/> This Page <br/> <Image Source="image.png"/>  </div> }/>
        <Panel inner={ <div> <Button ID="github_button" Class="Button" link="https://github.com/mikhail-zh-2009/Web-Page-One"/> System Converter <br/> <Image Source="project-web-page-one.png"/>  </div> }/>
        <Panel inner={ <div> <Button ID="github_button" Class="Button" link="https://github.com/mikhail-zh-2009/Web-Page-01.08.2022"/> Bubbles! <br/> <Image Source="project-bubbles.png"/>  </div> }/>
    </div>
}

root.render(<App/>)
```

Консоль:

```
Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: https://reactjs.org/link/react-devtools
You might need to use a local HTTP server (instead of file://): https://reactjs.org/link/react-devtools-faq // Я знаю, что здесь написано, что нужно использовать локальный сервер, но можно как-то обойтись без этого?
babel.min.js:24 
        
       You are using the in-browser Babel transformer. Be sure to precompile your scripts for production - https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/
u @ babel.min.js:24
index.html:1 
        
       Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/sukas/Desktop/web/14/App.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, edge, https, chrome-untrusted.
App.js:1 
        
       Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: Перенесите ваш код в сам HTML и всё должно заработать

Comment: @EzioMercer не работает

Comment: ты запускаешь сборку для разработки, в ней скрипты собираются бабелем непосредственно в браузере. Браузер пробует загрузить файл `app.js` и не может из-за cors. Для решения достаточно выполнить сборку проекта и запускать итоговый файл

Comment: @Grundy ♦ какую ещё сборку проекта? И что такое cors?

Comment: убери из имени файла `react.development.js` - `development`

Comment: @Павел, [CORS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Сборки у тебя действительно нет.

Comment: Проблема в том, что браузер не понимает jsx, для того чтобы он понял ты подключаешь babel, а он пытается делать запросы. Как итог, при отсутствия сервера - ты и получаешь ошибку. Решение тебе указано в тексте ошибки - тебе надо прекомпилировать скрипт `app.js`

Comment: Либо не использовать `jsx`

Comment: @Grundy Я убрал строку react.development.js из index.html, но теперь в консоли другая ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED')
    at react-dom.development.js:16:36
    at react-dom.development.js:13:29
    at react-dom.development.js:14:2

Comment: @Grundy и как прекомпилировать скрипт? Что надо для этого использовать? Просто у меня тут три файла: index.html, app.js, style.css и что из этого прекомпилировать и чем я не знаю.

Comment: @Grundy И JSX я не использовать не могу.

Comment: @Павел, конечно можешь, jsx - это просто синтаксический сахар - ты можешь его не использовать

Comment: @Grundy да, но с ним гораздо удобнее.

Comment: @Grundy и в документации он используется

Comment: в документации не подразумевается что ты будешь запускать без сборки :)

Comment: @Grundy Ну я бы запускал со сборкой, если бы вы мне объяснили, как это делать ;)

Comment: @Павел вот тут [примеры](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html)

Comment: @Grundy Да, я знаю что можно создать приложение на реакт с помощью npm и прочего мусора. Но я хочу, чтобы можно было просто запустить страницу и всё работало. Так нельзя сделать?

Comment: @Миша, там же есть примеры со сборкой, чтобы получить просто html на котором все работает

Comment: Имеется ввиду сборка jsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Только что проверил без всяких серверов, просто открыл HTML файл в браузере и всё заработало:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
        const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))

class Button extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }
    handleClick() {
        window.open(this.props.link, '_blank');
    }
    render() {
        return <button id={this.props.ID} className={this.props.Class} onClick={this.handleClick}>GitHub</button>
    }
}

class Panel extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.inner = this.props.inner
    }
    render() {
        return <div className="Panel">{this.inner}</div>
    }
}

class Image extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.inner = this.props.inner
    }
    render() {
        return <img src={this.props.Source} className="Panel-Image"/>
    }
}

function App() {
    return <div>
        <Panel inner={ <div> <Button ID="github_button" Class="Button" link="https://github.com/mikhail-zh-2009/React-Page"/> ReactJS Calculator <br/> <Image Source="project-react-page.png"/> </div> }/>
        <Panel inner={ <div> <Button ID="github_button" Class="Button" link="https://github.com/mikhail-zh-2009/React-Page-2"/> This Page <br/> <Image Source="image.png"/>  </div> }/>
        <Panel inner={ <div> <Button ID="github_button" Class="Button" link="https://github.com/mikhail-zh-2009/Web-Page-One"/> System Converter <br/> <Image Source="project-web-page-one.png"/>  </div> }/>
        <Panel inner={ <div> <Button ID="github_button" Class="Button" link="https://github.com/mikhail-zh-2009/Web-Page-01.08.2022"/> Bubbles! <br/> <Image Source="project-bubbles.png"/>  </div> }/>
    </div>
}

root.render(<App/>)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138324/discussion-on-answer-by-eziomercer------react).